# How to setup snowflake accounts for Prod and non prod?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do you set up Snowflake accounts in your company?

Every environment has its pros and cons. I want to know the majority of companies use which option. Thanks

Option 1:- Single Account (Prod, QA, Dev on the same account)

Option 2:- 2 Accounts/Separate Accounts (1 for prod, 1 for QA) may be in the future 1 for Dev

Option 3:- 2 Accounts (1 for Prod and 1 for QA & Dev)

I want someone help me to setup snowflake environment

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that there are no (internal or external) regulatory requirements that mandate how you separate prod and non-prod data...

I would always create separate accounts for Dev, Test, Prod, etc. This enables all objects to have the same name regardless of which "environment" they are in - which makes deployments, CI/CD, etc. much simpler.

It also makes it much harder, though obviously not impossible, to accidentally get Prod data into a non-Prod environment